# pandas not found after installation via pip

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

After installing python 3.6.7 for compatibility with tensorflow, I tried installing other modules I use via pip. After doing `pip3.6 install pandas` it seamed like the install was successful:

```
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas-0.23.4
```

however, after typing `python3`:

```
Python 3.6.7rc1 (v3.6.7rc1:311101f7b6, Sep 26 2018, 03:26:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and trying to import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I don't know what could have gone wrong, especially since I had no trouble on python3.7.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: Typically this is the result of the pip not being associated with the python install you think it is. What does `python3 -m pip show pandas`  return?  Is it listed in `python3 -m pip list`?

Comment: @DSM thanks a lot for the tip. In fact `python3 -m pip list` did not include `pandas` and upon the command `python3 -m pip install pandas`, pandas was installed again and works now. Could you explain, how it is possible, that it worked for `tensorflow, numpy, scipy` but not for `pandas, matplotlib` ?